# Не были пойманы / ни были пойманы

Tags: орфография, глаголы, не-с-глаголом

> Жрецы усердно трудились, пока в 228 году **ни/не** были пойманы.

Как правильно написать приведенное выше предложение? Чем обусловлен выбор написания *ни* или *не*?

Answer (score 2):

Думаю что, в предложении необходимо использовать частицу НЕ.

1. Частица НИ употребляется для усиления отрицания (в предложении его нет) и может быть заменена на союз **и** (у нас такая возможность отсутствует).
   *Ни* [и] *косточкой нигде не мог я поживиться* (Крылов).
2. В соединении с союзом **пока** частица НЕ употребляется в придаточных предложениях времени, обозначающих предел, до которого длится действие, выраженное сказуемым главного предложения.
   *Сиди тут, пока не приду.*

*Жрецы усердно трудились* (как долго? до какого момента?), *пока в 228 году **не** были пойманы.*

[Неударяемые частицы НЕ и НИ](http://n-t.ru/ac/56/og13.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: **Жрецы усердно трудились, пока в 228 году не были пойманы.**

Здесь отрицательная частица НЕ, а не усилительная частица НИ, так как это СПП **с придаточным времени** (союз ПОКА)

**Пояснение**

Если речь идет  **о сложноподчиненном предложении (как в данном случае),** то частица НИ употребляется **исключительно в придаточных уступительных  предложениях** с союзными словами ***где ни, когда ни, куда ни, сколько ни, как ни*** и т.д.  Но нужно убедиться, что это именно уступительные отношения.

Например: *Куда ни ступишь, везде вода.* Это  **уступительное** придаточное. Частицу НИ  в этом предложении **можно убрать**, так как она имеет только усилительное значение: *Куда наступишь, везде вода.*

Сравнить: *Это были места  (какие?), куда не ступала нога человеческая.*  Это придаточное определительное предложение, отрицательная частица НЕ, нет уступительных отношений.

2) Но возникает вопрос: **почему мы можем подозревать в заданном предложении усиление, а не отрицание?**

Я думаю, что это связано с особенностью союза ***ПОКА***, после которого возможно как употребление частицы НЕ, так и ее отсутствие (по аналогии с частицей НИ)

Например:

Ждали, пока все **соберутся**. Ждали, пока все **не собрались.**

Мы ждали, пока их всех **поймают**. Они трудились, пока их всех **не поймали**.

Эти парные варианты (***пока*** и ***пока не***) сходны с частицей НИ в уступительных предложениях, **когда НИ можно убрать,** а смысл предложения не изменится.